# I am always getting network error in recongition.onerror() Listener in Javascript Speech Recognition

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition, speech-recognition-api

I am creating one Application where I want to ask multiple question to user  as Voice input using speech Recognition in JavaScript,But When user gives first answer then Mike listens for long time even after The User stop speaking and in recognition.onerror() Event listener print's network error Message Even if My Internet is Working Properly,Can anybody help to solve this problem.